# mysql_affected_rows() returns 1 on a 'real' REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a MySQL table with one primary key.

Nightly I run a job to insert and update records. I use `REPLACE INTO` for each operation so it'll either add or replace the existing row.

After the `REPLACE INTO` query I call `mysql_affected_rows()` which is returning a count of 1 for many rows which are actually replaced and not 'new' (it returns 2 for the vast majority of rows which are replaced).

I know that some of these 'inserts' are false because I track the count of rows at the start and end of the batch update; the table has no duplicates to throw off that count, plus I've verified the faux 'new' rows existed before the batch update.

This table has nothing special about it; a similar table works as behaved with the same code. Anyone have any ideas why `mysql_affected_rows()` is returning 1 for an operation which is really a replace and not an insert?

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE INTO actually does a DELETE and then INSERT, not an UPDATE.

You might want to consider using  INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE   syntax instead.

Comment: I'm aware REPLACE does a delete/insert if the row already exists & that's what has me stumped - why is mysql_affected_rows() returning 1 when it clearly should be returning 2? As I mentioned, this code works on an identical table, so I'm lost trying to figure out why mysql_affected_rows() is returning 1.

I could use ON DUPLICATE, but would require all of the column & value labels twice-once for INSERT INTO & for ON DUPLICATE. With 600+ columns that's a lot. I can calc the changes between columns, but that would require doing a SELECT, defeating the point of using REPLACE in the 1st place.